# Kernel preemption while holding spinlock

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel, if kernel preemption is enabled while holding a spinlock, how can  deadlock occur ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kernel preemption doesn't guarantee that you don't have a deadlock.

A thread may still hold a lock without ever releasing it, and that would still cause a deadlock if some other thread wants to acquire that same lock. The thread that is holding the lock has to decide to release it to avoid deadlocks. That is to say the thread or some other logic has to preempt the thread **and** cause it to release the lock. The kernel itself can't cause the thread to release the lock.

The kernel simply can schedule other threads to run, but if some other thread depends on the first thread finishing then that thread will also get blocked.

For example:

Thread A is waiting on a lock for some shared resource that thread B has acquired.

Thread A get's preempted and thread B gets scheduled.

Thread B is waiting on a lock for some shared resource thread A is holding.

Deadlock. Neither thread A nor thread B can make progress.

To break the deadlock something has to preempt thread A or B to release it's lock. Kernel preemption can't do that.

Comment: <quote>A thread may still hold a lock without ever releasing it, that would still cause a deadlock.</quote>  I don't agree.  It may cause a deadlock, if some other thread needs to take the lock.  But there could be a lock that is only shared under some conditions, and when it is not shared a thread could just continue holding it (as an optimization).  Saying "failure to release a lock WILL cause a deadlock" is a little too strong.

Comment: @Ben: Agree. I clarified later under what conditions a deadlock will occur later. But, your point is valid. I'll revise the comment to make it more clear. Thanks.